# Aspnet5 File Upload

Tags: c#, html, .net, file-upload, asp.net-core

In Aspnet5 RC1, Web Application,
Consider a simple web application.
How to upload a file?
cshtml is not used, just a simple html file which calls a controller action

sample.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="Sample/Index">
        <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

SampleController.cs

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class Sample : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("Index")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {        
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                await file.SaveAsAsync(Path.Combine("G:\\", fileName));
            }            
        }
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

sample.html is loaded,
1 or many files are selected  from file  upload control.
When submit button is clicked, the control flow comes to the action
how much ever files are selected, in the **Index** action ,  count of **ICollection < IFormFile > files**  is always 0.
Unable to get the uploaded file in server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example html:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

If you don't want to use Url.Action then just put there proper url.

And here is the code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath,"uploads"); 
        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            if(file.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                await file.SaveAsAsync(Path.Combine(uploads,fileName));
            }
        return View();
        }
    }    
}
```

The controller has a constructor added that takes an IHostingEnvironment as a parameter. IHostingEnvironment is a service that provides some useful environment information such as the current file path to the wwwroot folder via the WebRootPath property. This is required when specifying the location for saving uploaded files.

Comment: so this html uses mvc, razor engine ? how to do the same using a plain html , without mvc razor engine

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post: http://damienbod.com/2015/12/05/asp-net-5-mvc-6-file-upload-with-ms-sql-server-filetable/

He is using Web API but this shouldn't be a problem. And he is also using a plain HTML form (but it doesn't really matter whether to use razor or plain HTML)